# PyQt5 - get the current window state (Maximized or not)

Tags: python, pyqt, window

I'm trying to make a config file that would contain information about window size, position and state when closing. When opening again it should recover based on that info.
So I'm using `closeEvent` to trigger this function:

```
cfg = ConfigParser()            # create config object   
def saveConfig(gui):
    winW = gui.centralwidget.frameGeometry().width()        # width of window
    winH = gui.centralwidget.frameGeometry().height()       # height of window
    
    cfg['window'] = {}                                      # window settings
    window = cfg['window']
    window['size'] = f"{winW},{winH}"                       # save current window size
    window['pos'] = f"{gui.x()},{gui.y()}"                  # save current window position
    
    with open(CONFIG_PATH, 'w') as file:                    # write config to file
         cfg.write(file)
```

Here's the loadConfig function:

```
def loadConfig(gui):
    cfg.read(CONFIG_PATH)       # read config from CONFIG_PATH

    if 'window' in cfg:         # window settings
        window = cfg['window']    
        size = window.get('size').split(',')
        pos = window.get('pos').split(',')
        gui.resize(int(size[0]), int(size[1]))  # resize window to saved size
        gui.move(int(pos[0]), int(pos[1]))      # move window to save position
    else:
        gui.resize(1110,783)
        gui.move(398,94)
```

However, if the window is closed while it's maximalized, it doesn't appear maximalized again after launch. Just in the same size and position.

I read that you can get windowState(). Then it would be easy to compare it if it's `Qt.WindowMaximized` but when I use `print(gui.centralwidget.windowState()` it returns `<PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.WindowStates object at 0x000001E7B1DBF970>`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using [`saveGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry) and [`restoreGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry)?

Comment: @musicamante No, I'd just like to have more control over it. But maybe it's just unnecessary complicated like that...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "more control", as those functions already provide all you're trying to achieve (and even more). Also, instead of using separate calls to `resize()` and `move()`, it's usually better to directly use `setGeometry()` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Qt enums and flags are integer or bitwise values, so they can be easily converted into "readable" format:

```
    state = int(self.windowState())
```

The flags can be also directly compared even without knowing the numeric value, using bitwise operators:

```
    isMaximized = self.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized
```

Note that you can just call the related convenience functions if you want to know a specific state: [`isMaximized()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#maximized-prop), [`isMinimized()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimized-prop) and [`isFullScreen()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#fullScreen-prop).

Finally, remember that Qt already provides [`saveGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry) and [`restoreGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry), which not only stores the geometry of the window, but also the screen number and geometry on which the widget currently is, which ensures that the window will be restored as much as possible as it was when the state was saved, while ensuring it's always visible anyway, even if the screen setup has changed.

Comment: Hi, very old comment but I'm trying something and it seems I can't cast Qt enums to integer anymore, at least with PyQt6 and python 3.11. I get a "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'WindowState'"

Comment: @ThylowZ Since PyQt6 all enums are actual Python [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum) objects. To get their integer value, use `SomeEnum.value`.